# Do you need to bake eevee characters for a short animation video

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, baking

I have my character unwrapped and made. I am unsure how if i need to do anything else like baking. Do i just unwrapp my character and add texture or do i need to do anything else. the animation will be in eevee. Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: As far as the question goes, the answer is *No* - Eevee is not a game engine rather a *render engine* so baking is no requirement. Suggest add more detail to your question about your actual goal.

Comment: hi i am making a short animation with a single character in eevee. I am just wondering if i needed to bake when texture painting my low poly character. So i dont even need to unwrap the character for texture painting???

Comment: @BlenderBA He didn’t say UV unwrapping wasn’t necessary…

Comment: Ok thanks, i really appreciate it

Comment: Texture painting has nothing to do with baking. As the name suggests 'baking' is used to simplify shaders or adding detail to a *low poly* model by using a normal map if you need to save resources eg. when using the character in a game engine. Still unclear what you're asking to me...

Comment: Thank you that was really useful. I was just wondering what baking was for and you have been a great help